# Two affine varieties which are isomorphic, but their projectivisations are not

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, localization, projective-varieties

I am learning Algebraic Geometry and came across the following question:

> Show $V(y-x^3) \cong V(y-x^2)$ as affine varieties in $\mathbb{A}^2$. Prove that their projectivisations in $\mathbb{P}^2$ are not isomorphic by computing the local ring at the point $p=[0:1:0]$.

I know how to do the first part (I used the inverse maps $[x:y] \to [x,x^3]$ and $[x,y] \to [x,x^2]$). However, I am having trouble computing the local ring at $p$. Intuitively, the projectivisation of $V(y-x^3)$ contains a singularity on the open cover $y\neq 0$ where we get $z^2=x^3$, whereas this is not the case for $V(y-x^2)$. However, I don't know how to compute the local ring, and I would find it very useful to go through this computation. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we homogenize the equations to $yz^2 - x^3$ and $yz - x^2$, respectively, then "dehomogenize" in a neighborhood of $[0:1:0]$ to $z^2 - x^3$ and $z - x^2$. Now the local rings are
$$
k[x, z]/(z^2 - x^3)_{(x, z)}
$$
and
$$
k[x, z]/(z - x^2)_{(x, z)}.
$$
and we want to prove these are not isomorphic. The bottom ring is  isomorphic to $k[t]_{(t)}$ via the map $x\mapsto t$, $z \mapsto t^2$.

The top ring cannot be isomorphic to $k[t]_{(t)}$. As you said, the idea of the proof is that the self-intersection point of the curve $z^2 - x^3$ is not smooth. We can formalize this in a lot of ways, but they all come down to proving that this ring is not a DVR. The easiest way to show this is to show that it's not integrally closed in its fraction field. Indeed, we have an embedding
$$
k[x, z]/(z^2 - x^3)_{(x, z)} \hookrightarrow k[t]_{(t)}.
$$
mapping $x \mapsto t^3$, $z \mapsto t^2$. Now $t$ is not in the image of this embedding, but is integral over the image (which is precisely $k[t^2, t^3]_{(t^2, t^3)}.$

Comment: To add some insight to what hunter is doing, the projectivisation of $y-x^2$ is a conic, so it is non-singular at every point. On the other hand, $y-x^3$ has a cusp at its point in infinity. Therefore the difference between these two projectivisations is that one of them is singular and another one is regular. To some extent this is what must happen if they are non-isomorphic, because two projective, irreducible, non-singular curves that have a couple of isomorphic open subsets must be isomorphic themselves

Comment: Thank you both, it makes a lot of sense!